# The referenced component system could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, reference

New project, no code at all just many installed libraries. Already getting 4 warnings saying that the following references could not be found: system, system.core, system.xml, system.xml.linq

I've added the references by checking them off after right clicking 'add references'
Have an android default as well as ios, but only the android references are giving me problems.

Does not seem to fix anything.
Any ideas?
VS2010 w/ xamarin & nethereum